# Using static property to communicate between two forms in multi-user environment

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, static

I am using one int `static property` to send an ID value from my SearchForm to MainForm.

```
static int _SrchRslt;
public static int SrchRslt
{
    get { return _SrchRslt; }
    set { _SrchRslt = value; }
}
```

and I am sending the value of this property from another form (searchform) as :

```
Mainform.SrchRslt = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSearch.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
this.Close();
```

With this I can search all details with my srchRslt value in MainForm. This process is well working in single user interface.

But in multi-user environments, if two users try to search at one time, this static property value will cause problems, because that same value is going to two persons. I hope you understand my problem.

Do you have any other suggestions to search between two forms?

Comment: 2 users == 2 instances of winform app. == 2 instances of static var...

Comment: weird, it should not happen, R U sure?

Comment: Can you clarify the multi-user setup? Are they on the same machine? Same logon session? Same process? (And if so: how?) What? But frankly: static properties (unless referring to configuration data) are generally a bad idea.

Comment: @MarcGravell:  Induvidual mechine and same login sessions. And process is Same.How?:Inserting , retrive from another search form and take them to main form and updating. Could you please give me any bettre Idea to take values from search dialog form to main form.

Comment: @user1875373 you just add the properties you want to expose to, say, the search form - and have your other form get and set them from a reference to it.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am trying this code.. is this correct one `In parent form //Declare public property public string ID { get; set; } //Create child form in some method. Form2 form2 = new Form2(this); form2.Show();In child form Form1 m_parent ; public Form2(Form1 frm1) { InitializeComponent(); m_parent = frm1; } m_parent.ID = textbox1.Text;`